# What is a timed attack?

Tags: server, server-side, server-side-attacks

I've heard the term, but I cannot find that much information on it on the internet. What is a timed attack with relation to web server scripting?
Are there methods to combat such attacks?

Answer (score 0):

Using proper terms is crucial. Sometimes also a context is needed.

If you mean [Timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) then you can read about that on Wikipedia. This can be used to reveal certain information about the system (see Examples section in that article) by analyzing how much time did the server spend to handle certain requests.

Or, it can refer to TOCTTOU types of attacks - see [this article](https://defuse.ca/race-conditions-in-web-applications.htm) for example.